# How to match the exact string and replace all with other string using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Recently I came across one issue where I need to change the double curly braces with triple curly braces ,

The below example could clarify the need further,

```
let mystring = '{{Hello Tom}} , {{How are you doing today}}'
```

I need to change the above string and replace "{{" and "}}" with "{{{" and "}}}" respectively.

Currently I am using regex as below,

```
let output_string = mystring.replace(/{{/g, "{{{").replace(/}}/g, "}}}")
```

At the first execution its working fine and I got the desired output as '{{{Hello Tom}}} , {{{How are you doing today}}}' , when the next execution happen , it changed to 4 curly braces like below,

Output after second execution,

```
'{{{{Hello Tom}}}} , {{{{How are you doing today}}}}'
```

Its keep on increasing the curly braces whenever event is repeated.

I just want to replace 2 curly braces with 3,not any further

How can I Achieve this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const output = input.replace(/\{+(.*?)\}+/g, (match, p1) => {
  return `{{{${p1}}}}`;
});
```

The regular expression pattern `/\{+(.*?)\}+/g` matches any number of curly braces, including none, and captures the text inside the braces in group 1.

**Demo**

```js
const input = '{{Hello Tom}} , {{How are you doing today}}';

const input2 = '{{{Hello Tom}}} , {{{How are you doing today}}}';

const input3 = '{{{{Hello Tom}}}} , {{{{How are you doing today}}}}';

const output = input.replace(/\{+(.*?)\}+/g, (match, p1) => {
  return `{{{${p1}}}}`;
});

const output2 = input2.replace(/\{+(.*?)\}+/g, (match, p1) => {
  return `{{{${p1}}}}`;
});

const output3 = input3.replace(/\{+(.*?)\}+/g, (match, p1) => {
  return `{{{${p1}}}}`;
});

console.log(output)
console.log(output2)
console.log(output3)
```

Comment: It worked. Cool!!! . Can you please help me where can I get more information about  these type of complex regex .

Comment: @RameshS I would advice you to look at something like https://regex101.com/ or other places, if you paste in the regex it will give you a little description of it